# Opening every links standing on a webpage at once

Tags: browser

I have to proofread every single page of a website. This website is quite hierarchically build.

Is there a way to open every links that stands on a page, each on a different tabs (one tab for each link standing on the page) ? This way I could be sure to have read everything by closing each tab after reading it.

The way I intend to do this job is :

- Open the home page
- Open each link found on that page to a separate tab
- repeat recursively on each newly opened page.

Answer (score 1):

Be careful having ALL links open automatically as there may be hundreds of them, which could cause your system to stop responding or to crash.

Using Firefox you can use the [LinkSidebar](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/linksidebar/) Add-on which gives you control of what to open.

Also found some other tools [here](https://www.squarefree.com/bookmarklets/pagelinks.html).

> These bookmarklets let you quickly search, open, or list links on whatever page you're viewing.

Answer (score 0):

You can open all links once in chrome browser, Bookmark all open pages using Ctrl+Shift+D and save this in separate bookmark folder.
Next time you can open all links in the bookmark folder from bookmark menu.